# AS3 getDefinitionByName - Error #1065: Variable {class name} is not defined

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My issue is slightly more complicated than the title suggests. I work for a company that has in the region of 20 flash games. Our players also have avatars which they can customise and these avatars are used inside our games.

We have a file, Avatar.swf which is loaded by our preloader and then passed into GameName.swf. I want to take this Avatar movieclip and create a factory class so we can have many instances of it inside our games.

I can get an instance of the Avatar movieclip from the loader without a problem. There are two way I know of to get a constructor from an instance in AS3.

1.) Object(myInstance).constructor as Class

2.) getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(myInstance)) as Class

1 works intermittently but about 1 time in 3 I get a null reference error thrown by the resultant instance. I have no idea why but it is not a consistent problem. It's almost as if the scripts are there but the assets library isn't. It happens both in debug mode and release mode. It also happens both when compiled using FlashDevelop and CS5.5.

2 throws Error #1065: Variable Avatar is not defined. I understand this is because I have not imported the Avatar package and declared a dummy instance of Avatar but this is the whole point. If we change the avatar by adding a new item of clothing for example, we definitely do not want to have to go through our ever expanding list of games and recompile them all. In other words, I do not want the Avatar code in every game, it would negate the point of loading it in our preloader.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an [`ApplicationDomain`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e07.html) issue. What app domain are you loading the other swfs into?

Comment: I suggest that you shouldn't use `getDefinitionByName()` at all. Although it works, I think it's better to refer to specific application domain with `appDomain.getDefinition()`. With `getDefinitionByName()` you rely on classes being added to current scope depending on app domain you specify in loader context. Instead, you could request a definition from app domain of the loaded content. This will always work if you really have a definition there: `loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition('definition')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your Avatar.swf is loaded into the same [application domain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSd75bf4610ec9e22f43855da312214da1d8f-8000.html).
2. Make sure you have used each of the avatar classes [at least once](http://jwopitz.wordpress.com/2008/02/21/getdefinitionbyname-trick/) (e.g. in the document class of Avatar.swf), or if they are Flash library items, export them into frame 1 of Avatar.swf.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm pretty sure they are both in the same domain but I haven't seen that documentation so I will have a double look. Might this explain the intermittent errors using Object(instance).constructor? With regards the second link, I've seen it already but I do not want the code to be part of each game because then I would have to recompile all the games every time I made a change to the avatar. This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: No on both counts: The `Object(instance).constructor` statement will only cause an error if `instance` is `null`, hence there is probably an issue with the load operation not being finished.  And the important part in 2. is that you use the classes (or export into frame 1) within the *loaded* class, which you will have to recompile anyway, when you change its content.  It is necessary, though, to have the classes you want to instantiate included into the binary - otherwise there won't be anything to find for `getDefinitionByName`.